# Why does Github show older commits when creating PR across branches?

Tags: github

I have seen a few posts here in Stackoverflow but nothing specific to my use case.
We essentially have TWO branches - one for testing in QA (**sprint**)and one for release(**master**).

Our normal deployment works thus:

```
Forked from sprint ----> Create PR ----> Merge to **sprint** Upstream (Deploys to QA)
spring Upstream    ----> Create PR ----> Merge to **master** (Deploys to PROD)
```

The problem we keep facing is after we MERGE our changes to **master** for say Feature A, when we go through the same motions for a new feature for Feature B by a different developer, who merges to sprint and then on creating the final PR to **master** - we see the commits there were PREVIOUSLY merged to the **master** from **sprint** start showing up for this  developer. Even though he had rebased/pulled from **sprint** upstream prior to creating his **sprint** PR to get the changes pushed by the previous developer.

Why does **master** PR merge keep accumulating the old commits already merged?

[image: Added Merge Settings]

Comment: Are you using squash merges?

Comment: yes - we use squash and merge at both branches

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you have two long-running branches and are using squash merge.  The [Git FAQ is clear that this just can't work](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#long-running-squash-merge):

> In general, there are a variety of problems that can occur when using squash merges to merge two branches multiple times. These can include seeing extra commits in `git log` output, with a GUI, or when using the `...` notation to express a range, as well as the possibility of needing to re-resolve conflicts again and again.
>
> When Git does a normal merge between two branches, it considers exactly three points: the two branches and a third commit, called the merge base, which is usually the common ancestor of the commits. The result of the merge is the sum of the changes between the merge base and each head. When you merge two branches with a regular merge commit, this results in a new commit which will end up as a merge base when they’re merged again, because there is now a new common ancestor. Git doesn’t have to consider changes that occurred before the merge base, so you don’t have to re-resolve any conflicts you resolved before.
>
> When you perform a squash merge, a merge commit isn’t created; instead, the changes from one side are applied as a regular commit to the other side. This means that the merge base for these branches won’t have changed, and so when Git goes to perform its next merge, it considers all of the changes that it considered the last time plus the new changes. That means any conflicts may need to be re-resolved. Similarly, anything using the `...` notation in `git diff`, `git log`, or a GUI will result in showing all of the changes since the original merge base.

GitHub is using this exact same behavior of finding the merge base under the hood to find out which commits are on your branch, and therefore suffers from all of the same problems that Git itself does.

There is no way to make this work with squash merges and you will have to use a merge commit.

Comment: Updated the Question Body with an image of our Github Settings. Are you suggesting that i uncheck the SQUASH and MERGE option? Are the other two settings correct?

Comment: You can keep it enabled if you want for other merges, but you cannot use it to merge these two branches.  If you're not sure what to do, just turn it off altogether and use merge commits.